# How to delete and edit items on the Sequelize database through controllers?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, controller, sequelize.js

I'm new to sequelize and am trying to build an app where I can delete and edit the items that are stored in an array in the database. However, I do not know how to delete as the console kept giving me errors that the `handleDelete` is not a function.

How do I allow user to edit the data such as product name in the backend too? Are there any methods for that? Thank you.

Here's my controller in the backend.

```
class ProductsController extends BaseController {
  constructor(model, userModel) {
    super(model);
    this.userModel = userModel;
  }

  // CRUD functions for products belonging to a user
  async getAllProducts(req, res) {
    try {
      const output = await this.model.findAll();
      return res.json(output);
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: true, msg: err });
    }
  }

  async getOneProduct(req, res) {
    const { productId } = req.body;
    try {
      const product = await this.model.findByPk(productId, {
        include: [
          {
            model: this.userModel,
            through: { attributes: [] },
          },
        ],
      });
      return res.json(product);
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: true, msg: err });
    }
  }

  async deleteProduct(req, res) {
    const { productId } = req.body;
    try {
      return !!(await this.model.destroy({
        where: {
          id: productId,
        },
      }));
    } catch (e) {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

For my frontend, here is my homepage where I call the list of products,

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import ProductsList from "./ProductList";

export default function Home() {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [ids, setIDs] = useState();

  const getData = async () => {
    let API = await axios.get(`localhost:3000/products`);
    setProducts(API.data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  const handleDelete = async (ids) => {
    let product= {
      id: ids,
    };
    let response = await axios.delete(`localhost:3000/products/${ids}`, {
      data: product,
    });

    getData();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Link to="/">
        {
          <ProductsList
            products={products}
            ids={ids}
            setIDs={setIDs}
            handleDelete={handleDelete}
          />
        }
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And here is the component where the delete button is placed.

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const ProductsList = ({ products, ids, setIDs, handleDelete }) => {
  return (
    <div className="Overall">
      {products.map((product, index) => (
        <div className="container">
          {setIDs(product.id)}
          <Link
            to={`/products/${index + 1}`}
            key={product.id}
          >
            <div>
              {product.name}
              <br />
              <br />
              <button onClick={() => handleDelete(ids)}>Delete</button>
            </div>
          </Link>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductsList;
```

This is the component that renders out the page of single product

```
export default function singleProduct() {
  // react routes
  const params = useParams();
  const [single, setSingle] = useState([]);

  const getSingle = async () => {
    let singleProduct = await axios.get(`localhost:3000/products`);
    setSingle(singleProduct.data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getSingle();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {single
        .filter((product) => Number(params.productId) === Number(product.id))
        .map((product) => {
          return (
            <div>
              <p>{product.name}</p>
            </div>
          );
        })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Nothing *overtly* seems out of place here *other than* that you are rendering a button without a `type` attribute (*so it has `type="submit"` by default*) within a `Link` component, so any button click events will bubble, i.e. propagate, up to the link and activate it. Perhaps there's an issue with *where* the delete handler is declared and a navigation action is unmounting that component. Can you share how these components are rendered as routed content, i.e. the router and routes?

Comment: Sure, when I'm at **"/home"**, the page will render out a list of contents from the ProductList Components so it would be **"/products"**. However, if I were to click on individual content, it would bring me to the singleProduct page (**"/products/1"**) for the first item.  I placed the delete button on every item in the ProductList Component.

Comment: Can you create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that reproduces the `handleDelete` function issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: Hi I've managed to solve it. Thanks for your help!